# Wix installer project git repository

Tags: c#, git, tfs, wix, continuous-integration

We have two teams. 
One responsible for Dev of a certain C# project the other responsible for installers and deployment. Both are maintaining a repository, one for main project one for installer project. 
The project and  installer are meant to be built automatically during a tfs build process.

- Should the repositories of both elements be combined in one repo? Or left in two different ones?
- Is it even possible to have them in different repos and access them from one build process?

Comment: As far as i know, Wix installer projects can be part of one solution. So it does not matter if different teams is doing development, this can be in a single repo. The division is in your org, but if you see, they can be part of same team who is doing main project and installer development.

Answer (score 1):

TFS build is **not allow** dependencies on multiple source repositories.

There has been a feature request in uservoice and you can vote up for it to get more attention.

> **Allow TFS build to depend on multiple repositories**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11592954-allow-tfs-build-to-depend-on-multiple-repositories

As for ombined in one repo or left in two different ones, it's based on your team's requirements. If you only want to keep one build process, it' better to ombined in one.